# How can I plot different plots out of multiple data files with only one plotting script?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Up until now I had been using a script to plot a set of data out one file. Now I have a lot of similar files of the same measurements but for different days and instead of running the program 30 times I want to be able to use one program to plot all figures. I have a big script so I didn't know what to write here. I've thought of just putting a loop for, and changing the filename, but I'm not sure how to do this effectively.

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Agg')

from ceiloclass import ceilo 

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os


import fileinput

filename='ceilo.dat'

....Bunch of code that configures plotting
....

plt.savefig('ceilo.png')

plt.show()
```

Comment: use the OO interface instead of the state-machine interface http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles

Answer (score 0):

Are all the files set up similarly? Similar columns, etc.? If so, create a new list and, while looping over every file, append the data to that list.

```
all_data = []
for file in files:
    # Your reading commands
    all_data.append(this_file_data)
```

Then, you can plot `all_data` just once.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to first generate a list of filenames of the current working directory, and then use a for loop to iterate through those files. In your code, instead of using explicit filename strings, you would just pass the iteration variable (i.e. filename)

```
import glob,os
os.chdir("C:\\folder")
filelist=glob.glob("*.dat")
for filename in fileslist:
    file=open(filename,"wb")
    ....Bunch of code that configures plotting
    ....
    plt.savefig(filename[:-3]+"png")
    plt.show()
```

To install the glob library, open the command prompt and type "pip install glob".